# Create check for button that will create a error (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, null

My code takes a image from `letImageVIEW` and tries to place the image on lets just call it `imageviewB`. The problem is that if there is no image on `letImageVIEW` the app crashes.

How can I implement a check to prevent my app crashing if there is no image on `letImageVIEW`?

```
  @IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
     let left:UIImage = letImageVIEW.image!
     left.draw(in: CGRect(x: newSize2.width/10.0,y: newSize2.height/8.9,width: newSize2.width/2.5,height:   newSize2.height/1.29), blendMode:CGBlendMode.normal, alpha:1.0)
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    if let left:UIImage = letImageVIEW.image {
          left.draw(in: CGRect(x: newSize2.width/10.0,y: newSize2.height/8.9,width: newSize2.width/2.5,height:   newSize2.height/1.29), blendMode:CGBlendMode.normal, alpha:1.0)
    }else {
         print("No Image...")
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unwrap the option image by using `guard` 
    Please find below example.

```
  @IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {

     guard let left = letImageVIEW.image else {return}
         left.draw(in: CGRect(x: newSize2.width/10.0,y: newSize2.height/8.9,width: newSize2.width/2.5,height:   newSize2.height/1.29), blendMode:CGBlendMode.normal, alpha:1.0)

     }
```